# spring kafka ssl classpath truststore

Tags: java, ssl, spring-kafka

How can I use with spring kafka(without sboot) for SSL configuration a relative/classpath path for specifying location of truststore for example?

It works only when absolute path is provided.

Suprisingly it works with relative path(within jar) when runnig with spring boot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is read by Kafka, not Spring.

Kafka has no knowledge of Spring's classpath resource abstraction.

I think you are mistaken about boot; it only works there if the jar is exploded; boot has this code in `KafkaProperties`...

```
    map.from(this::getTrustStoreLocation).as(this::resourceToPath)
            .to(properties.in(SslConfigs.SSL_TRUSTSTORE_LOCATION_CONFIG));

...

private String resourceToPath(Resource resource) {
    try {
        return resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
                "Resource '" + resource + "' must be on a file system", ex);
    }
}
```

To use a truststore from within a jar, you would need to first copy it to a filesystem (e.g. `/tmp`) before starting the application context.

Comment: how can you avoid that, if you can not copy it to the filesytem ?

Comment: There is an [open JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7685) for Kafka to support reading the trust store from the classpath. It looks like there is a work-around in a comment there.

Answer (score 0):

My patch for this was to copy the key-store over to the filesystem while spring boots up. (rather have your own ConsumerFactory than the one from KafkaAutoConfiguration)

1. take the name of the key-store from your properties (so the key-store can be named different in your stages DEV/INT/PROD)
2. copy it the  filesystem of your k8n pod (use different target than '/tmp', if your run locally on Windows)
3. update the KafkaProperties with the new location in the file system.

```java
    @Configuration
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class KafkaConfig {
    
        private final KafkaProperties kafkaProps;
    
        @Bean
        @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "spring.kafka.enabled", havingValue = "true")
        public ConsumerFactory<?, ?> consumerFactory() throws IOException {
            Path fileSystemKeyStorePath = Paths.get("/tmp", "keystore.pfx");
    
            Resource keyStoreLocationFromProperties = kafkaProps.getSsl().getKeyStoreLocation();
            Files.copy(keyStoreLocationFromProperties.getInputStream(),
                fileSystemKeyStorePath, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    
            Ssl ssl = kafkaProps.getSsl();
            ssl.setKeyStoreLocation(new FileSystemResource(fileSystemKeyStorePath));
    
            return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory(kafkaProps.buildConsumerProperties());
        }
    }
```